# How to make about, and other pages in cake php

Tags: cakephp-2.0

i am new in cakephp so pls help me How to make about, and other pages in cake php

and tell me how to design this page no

thanks Rajesh

Answer (score 1):

**CakePHP** ships with a default controller PagesController.php. This is a simple and optional controller for serving up static content. The home page you see after installation is generated using this controller. If you make the view file app/View/Pages/about_us.ctp you can access it using the url http://example.com/pages/aboutus. You are free to modify the Pages Controller to meet your needs.

For example :
your **PagesController.php**

```
 public function aboutus()
 {
    // do something
 }
```

And your create  view file in your app/view/pages/aboutus.ctp.Then open your app/Config/routes.php and add this line according to your need.

```
Router::connect('/about-us', array('controller' => 'page','action'=>'aboutUs'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom page by creating one controller specialised for all static page.

Or you can make use of PageController.

To beautify your url to something like /about-us or /contact, open your app/Config/routes.php and add this line according to your need.

```
Router::connect('/about-us', array('controller' => 'page','action'=>'aboutUs'));
```